# interact.js drag/drop referencing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, interact.js

So, this is maybe just a question for interact.js users or I am missing something completely..

I was looking for a javascript library that provides me with drag/drop/scale/rotate and touch functionality for all those given functionalities. So, I stumbled upon interact.js, yet I seem to have a problem referencing elements while using the onDrop method:

I'll just take the code of the interact.js page, which I'm providing you here: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyy2N/2/

The part that is making problems is:

```
$(event.relatedTarget.id).hide();
```

which doesn't do anything, yet also doesn't throw any errors. More so:

```
$('#yes-drop').hide();
```

works, so does:

```
console.log(event.relatedTarget.id);
```

which returns the id as expected. Is this an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: One should actually use the correct syntax if one wants code to run correctly...

```
$('#'+event.relatedTarget.id).hide();
```

This would actually be a correct and working solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/Zyy2N/3/

Answer (score 1):

Sligthly better:

```
    $(event.relatedTarget).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zyy2N/8/